# LEFT JOIN selecting conditions

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join

```
SELECT * FROM messages as t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT topic_id date_seen FROM seen_log_ex WHERE member_id = :uid
) as t2
ON t1.topic_id=t2.topic_id AND t2.date_seen < t1.post_date
```

I want to select the row from messages if the table t2 doesn't contain its topic_id.

I want to select the row from messages if the table t2 contains its topic_id and `t2.date_seen < t2.post_date`

I DO NOT want to select the row from messages if the table t2 contains its topic_id and `t2.date_seen >= t2.post_date`

My query gives wrong results. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add sample data for better understanding?

Comment: It is a forum script. 'messages' table contains columns like message_id, topic_id, message_content etc. And 'seen_log_ex' table contains the columns member_id, topic_id and date_seen (date of user's last visit to that topic). I'm trying to select all the messages the topic of which isn't visited by the user or visited before the post_date of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you still need `member_id = :uid` inside the subquery, but the rest of the logic should be in `WHERE`, not in `ON` of the `LEFT JOIN`.

It also assumes that `seen_log_ex` has zero or one row for each `topic_id`. If it can have more than one row for `topic_id` results would be incorrect.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    messages as t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT topic_id date_seen FROM seen_log_ex WHERE member_id = :uid
    ) as t2
    ON t1.topic_id=t2.topic_id
WHERE
    t2.date_seen < t1.post_date
    OR t2.topic_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This query and query from the accepted answer return different results. Why do you say that they both work?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I edited the other query a bit before executing. That answer led me to the solution but it is wrong itself. My mistake. Your answer is the correct one. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

what about;

```
select * from messages m left join seen_log_ex l
on m.topic_id = l.topic_id
where 
(l.topic_id is null OR l.date_seen < l.post_date)
and l.member_id = :uid
```

Comment: @Wellenbrecher This query will not return a row from `messages` if the table `seen_log_ex` doesn't contain its `topic_id`, because `l.member_id = :uid` is in the  `where` clause. In the question it was stated that he wants to return such rows.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Oops, sorry. I edited this query a bit before executing. This answer led me to the solution but it is wrong itself. My mistake.

Comment: Corrected version;
select * from messages m left join seen_log_ex l
on m.topic_id = l.topic_id
where 
l.topic_id is null OR (l.date_seen < l.post_date
and l.member_id = :uid)